Cannot use postgis in GitHub action
I'm trying to install and use PostGIS in my GitHub action but it always fails. This is what I have so far:
tests:
name: PostgreSQL
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write
  repository-projects: write
  issues: write

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:latest
    env:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_tests
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 3

steps:
  - name: Enable PostGIS extension
    run: |
      PGPASSWORD=password psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres_user -d postgres_tests -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;"
    env:
      PGPORT: 5432


  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - uses: ./.github/actions/prepare-backend-app
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}


  - name: Run tests
    env:
      DB_CONNECTION: pgsql
      DB_DATABASE: postgres_tests
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USERNAME: postgres_user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
    run: php artisan test

But I'm always getting PDOException: SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist at character 123. I also tried to create another user as SUPERUSER but it's not working either.
Any help? Thank you.


I'm guessing this PDOException means the error is coming from php artisan test. 2) I'm betting type "geometry" does not exist occurs because of a search_path issue, where the schema that geometry exists in is not in the search_path.


How do you add that? I've installed PostGIS locally without defining any paths.

I think you are misunderstanding what path I am talking about. Read search_path

By default Postgis is installed in public, which is also by default in the user search path. See this post.

@JGH But how to check that in a GitHub action?

I would do is attempt the install without the Run tests. If it completes without an error then you know it is in the tests. Then you can go through them and look for anything that changes the search_path.

@AdrianKlaver This is the output of search_path:           search_path
"$user", public, topology, tiger
(1 row)


Add the information as update to question text. Including how you determined the search_path.  2) Did you verify that PostGIS is installed in public? Add information as text update top question text.

